# Create an array where each element stores its indices

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2d numpy array where every element is a tuple of its indices.

Example (4x5):

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 4]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[3, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4]]])
```

I would create an python `list` with the following list comprehension:

```
[[(y,x) for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
```

Is there a faster way to achieve the same, maybe with numpy methods?

Comment: Technically you are showing a 3d array (4,5,2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an initialization based method -

```
def create_grid(m,n):
    out = np.empty((m,n,2),dtype=int) #Improvement suggested by @AndrasDeak
    out[...,0] = np.arange(m)[:,None]
    out[...,1] = np.arange(n)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: create_grid(4,5)
Out[47]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 4]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[3, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Runtime test for all approaches posted thus far on `(4,5)` grided and bigger sizes -

```
In [111]: %timeit np.moveaxis(np.indices((4,5)), 0, -1)
     ...: %timeit np.mgrid[:4, :5].swapaxes(2, 0).swapaxes(0, 1)
     ...: %timeit np.mgrid[:4,:5].transpose(1,2,0)
     ...: %timeit create_grid(4,5)
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.1 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 17 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.51 µs per loop

In [113]: %timeit np.moveaxis(np.indices((400,500)), 0, -1)
     ...: %timeit np.mgrid[:400, :500].swapaxes(2, 0).swapaxes(0, 1)
     ...: %timeit np.mgrid[:400,:500].transpose(1,2,0)
     ...: %timeit create_grid(400,500)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop
```

Comment: `.swapaxes(-1, 0)` gives a different output, so comparing the timing is not very meaningfull

Comment: That second `:,:` could be replaced with a `...` to match the first, right?

Comment: @Eric Yup, had to fix on that runtime test.

Comment: The implementation of `np.indices` looks pretty weird to me, which explains why your solution is so much faster

Comment: Ok, I've [submitted a patch](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8629) that should bring these timings more in line

Comment: @Eric Awesome !

Comment: Would `np.empty` vs `np.zeros` make any difference?

Comment: Update: it indeed seems to, `465 mus` -> `317 mus` on my system if I change `np.zeros` to `np.empty`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yup! Some noticeable improvement, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: yay, my answer isn't the slowest :-D Probably not worth it to create a numba-function here but it's tempting if it could beat yours. :)

Answer (score 9):

Do you do this because you need it or just for sport? In the former case:

```
np.moveaxis(np.indices((4,5)), 0, -1)
```

`np.indices` does precisely what its name suggests. Only it arranges axes differently to you. So we move them with `moveaxis`

As @Eric points out one attractive feature of this method is that it works unmodified at arbitrary number of dimensions:

```
dims = tuple(np.multiply.reduceat(np.zeros(16,int)+2, np.r_[0, np.sort(np.random.choice(16, np.random.randint(10)))]))
# len(dims) == ?
np.moveaxis(np.indices(dims), 0, -1) # works
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that works for `ndim != 2`

Comment: Or with the base transpose method: `np.indices((4,5)).transpose(1,2,0)`

Comment: @hpaulj as Eric points out `moveaxis(..., 0, -1)` works for any number of dimensions. With the `transpose` you might find yourself reduced to `roll`ing an `arange` just to set up the shuffle axes ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can abuse `numpy.mgrid` or `meshgrid` for this purpose:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.mgrid[:4,:5].transpose(1,2,0)
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 4]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[3, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy.mgrid` and swap it's axes:

```
>>> # assuming a 3x3 array
>>> np.mgrid[:3, :3].swapaxes(-1, 0)
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1]],

       [[0, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 2]]])
```

That still differs a bit from your desired array so you can roll your axes:

```
>>> np.mgrid[:3, :3].swapaxes(2, 0).swapaxes(0, 1)
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

---

Given that someone timed the results I also want to present a manual [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) based version that "beats 'em all":

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def _indexarr(a, b, out):
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            out[i, j, 0] = i
            out[i, j, 1] = j
    return out

def indexarr(a, b):
    arr = np.empty([a, b, 2], dtype=int)
    return _indexarr(a, b, arr)
```

Timed:

```
a, b = 400, 500
indexarr(a, b)  # numba needs a warmup run
%timeit indexarr(a, b)                                  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop
%timeit np.mgrid[:a, :b].swapaxes(2, 0).swapaxes(0, 1)  # 100 loops, best of 3: 7.17 ms per loop
%timeit np.mgrid[:a, :b].transpose(1,2,0)               # 100 loops, best of 3: 7.47 ms per loop
%timeit create_grid(a, b)                               # 100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop
```

and on a smaller array:

```
a, b = 4, 5
indexarr(a, b)
%timeit indexarr(a, b)                                 # 100000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop
%timeit np.mgrid[:a, :b].swapaxes(2, 0).swapaxes(0, 1) # 10000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
%timeit np.mgrid[:a, :b].transpose(1,2,0)              # 10000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop
%timeit create_grid(a, b)                              # 10000 loops, best of 3: 32.3 µs per loop
```

As promised it "beats 'em all" in terms of performance :-)

Comment: Interesting that `swapaxes` is a method but `moveaxis` is not

Comment: With base transpose: `np.mgrid[:4,:5].transpose(1,2,0)`

Comment: Well, never fails! I don't think it's fair though comparing against NumPy ones ;)

Comment: Nice one! Now you only have to generalise to arbitrary ndim ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer I think almost all answers have some problem with arbitary dimensions (especially for `ndim >= 3` it's not really clear in what order the indices should appear).

Comment: What's wrong with row-major? Or should that be hyper-row-major?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Well currently `[[(y,x) for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]` could mean that the indices should be reversed _or_ that first and the last axis should be moved to first. In the second case your answer is correct but that still leaves the first case.