# How to I efficiently transform a numpy image of shape (w, h, 3) to (w,h,5) which has r,g,b,x,y in third axis?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Without using for loop.

How can I attach the x,y coordinate on to each pixel of a rgb image in numpy?

such that

`image[0,0,:] = (r,g,b,x,y)`  where x,y is the coordinate of the pixel

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42302348/7207392) for how to create the x, y, bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `rgb` and `xy` are your (w,h,3) and (w,h,2) arrays, respectively. Then you can concatenate them along the third axis:

```
image = np.concatenate((rgb, xy), axis=2)
```

Comment: And you can use `numpy.indices` with `numpy.moveaxis` to get the `xy` you want